# Is there a method in Java or Spring 2 that strips out certain characters to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a method similar to what is used in PHP to prevent sql injection for Spring 2. Are there any or so I need to make one

Comment: Just create good sane queries and never concatenate plain `String`s in your queries. Also, use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` (in case you're directly working with JDBC).

Comment: I agree, `PreparedStatement` is the way to avoid SQL injection attacks, not stripping out certain characters.

Comment: Just to reiterate, used PreparedStatements. SQL side these are handled differently than normal queries intentionally to protect against SQL Injection. 
-Edit, make sure you also reuse the PreparedStatements if they are being executed repeatedly, by making use of .clearParamters() and resetting the values, or you force the SQL engine to rebuild its execution plan each time. This still protects you against SQL Injection, but you take a performance hit if you dont reuse them appropriately.

Comment: It's always better to whitelist, than to blacklist. That is, assume all characters are bad, except for ones that you say are good. For example, if the user is entering a phone number, there's no reason for them to enter anything but numbers. This has more purpose even than just preventing SQL Injections. Even with the right prepared statements, if they put some code and it gets inserted into your databases, it may be read by java code after and inject in other ways. Saying that prepared statements make you safe is nothing short of naive. However they are still NECESSARY

Comment: The tldr; of my previous comment: PreparedStatements are a necessary but not sufficient condition for preventing sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OWASP site on this very question](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet): "SQL Injection is best prevented through the use of [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29)."

Stripping out characters is more along the lines of what you'd want to do to prevent [cross site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Persistent).